# Why do I get a Type Mismatch Error

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to write a subroutine in VBA for Excel to create a customer price list.

When I step through the routine I get a type mismatch at the line where I have placed the asterisk.  Can someone explain what I am doing wrong please?  Below is the code as I written it so far and there may be more errors that I have yet to discover.

```
Sub Create_Customer_Price_List()

    Dim Counter1 As Integer
    Dim Counter2 As Integer
    Dim SectionNum As Integer
    Dim ProdNum As Integer
    Dim ProductID As String
    Dim ProductSection As String

    Worksheets("BH").Activate

    SectionNum = Range("J10", Range("J10").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    Range("J10").Select

    For Counter1 = 1 To SectionNum
        If ActiveCell.Value <> 0 Then
        ProductSection = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
 *       Range("B9").Offset(Range("B9").End(xlDown), 3).Value = ProductSection


        End If

            ProdNum = Range("J10").Value

            For Counter2 = 1 To ProdNum
            ProductID = Range("L10").Value & Counter2

            Range("B9").Offset(Counter2, 0).Value = ProductID

            Next Counter2
        Range("J10").Offset(Counter1 + 1, 0).Select

    Next Counter1

End Sub
```

Comment: What cell are you trying to write `ProductSection` to?  Using the last cell in the column as the row offset doesn't really make a lot of sense.

Comment: You should avoide using `Activate`, `Select` and `ActiveCell`, instead use `With Worksheets("BH")` , `If .Cells("J" & 10 + Counter1).Value <> 0 Then`

Comment: Thanks for the comments and I understand the reasons for them.  When I have applied this I get an invalid procedure call or argument error.  Sorry, I'm quite new to VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Range("B9").Offset(Range("B9").End(xlDown), 3).Value = ProductSection`

should be:

`Range("B9").Offset(Range("B9").End(xlDown).Row, 3).Value = ProductSection`

You need to get the row, which will be a number